# Circular dependency issue in c++

Tags: c++

A minimalistic circular dependency issue I got today while working on a complex library is as follows

```
class Something; 

class Test
{
   public:
   int i;
   void process()
   {
     Something S;
     S.doSomething();
   }
};

class Something
{
   public:
   void doSomething()
   {
     Test t;
     t.i = 10;
   }
};

int main()
{
   Test t;
   t.process();
}
```

> test.cxx:10:16: error: aggregate ‘Something S’ has incomplete type and
>   cannot be defined
>         Something S;

What would be the minimal code change to make this work?
Rearranging the `Test` or `Something` classes just swaps the error.
One I could think of was use a global/static function in `doSomething()` which does the operation related to `Test t` object. What would be the better way?

Comment: looks like it's time to re-design ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because only the *implementation* depends on the other class, it's easy to move them out of class definition.

In a single source file that would be just to move `Test::process` definition after defining `class Something`.

```
class Test
{
   public:
   int i;
   void process();
};

class Something
{
   public:
   void doSomething()
   {
     Test t;
     t.i = 10;
   }
};

// a function defined inside its class definition is an inline member function
inline
void Test::process()
{
    Something S;
    S.doSomething();
}

int main()
{
   Test t;
   t.process();
}
```

Comment: So I have forgot the basics of c++ with years of experience :)